# My view does not update when model change sapui5

Tags: json, data-binding, sapui5

Good Morning,

I have this problem which I have been trying to solve for a couple of days and I couldn't find the answer, nor my colleagues.

My problem is that I bind two boolean values in a JSON to two different **visible** properties. The initial value of the JSON is correctly binded but when modify my json the change does not reflect in my view.

Please note that all the **Constants** Strings are correct.

My JSON initialization:

```
onInit : function(){
    var inputModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({            
        inputEditable: true,
        formVisible: true
    });
    this.getView().setModel(inputModel, Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP);

},
```

Property formVisible binding:

```
new sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm({
                editable: true,
                layout: sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleFormLayout.ResponsiveGridLayout,
                labelSpanXL: 1,
                labelSpanL: 2,
                labelSpanM: 2,
                labelSpanS: 3,
                visible:"{"+Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP+">/formVisible}",
                content: [ 

                    new sap.m.VBox({
                    visible : true,   
                    items:[
                        new sap.m.HBox({
                            items: [
                                new sap.m.RadioButton({

                                    groupName : "Group1",
                                    text : "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">completeName}",
                                    select : [oController.controlCampos, oController],
                                    selected : true,                                
                                }),
                                new sap.m.Input("inputNombre",{
                                    enabled : "{"+Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP+">/inputEditable}",                                                                                
                                    //type : sap.m.InputType.Text,
                                    placeholder : "Introduzca nombre completo"
                                })
                            ]
                        }),
                        new sap.m.HBox({
                            items : [
                                new sap.m.RadioButton({
                                    groupName : "Group1",
                                    text : "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">user}",                             
                                }),
                                new sap.m.Input("inputUsuario",{                                        
                                    enabled : 
                                    {
                                        path: Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP+">/inputEditable",       
                                        formatter : formatter.generic.negate                                     
                                    },
                                    //type : sap.m.InputType.Text,
                                    placeholder : "Usuario" //TODO i18n
                                })
                            ]
                        })


                    ]
                   })
                ]
                }).addStyleClass("scopeSelectorForm"),                    
                new sap.m.Bar({
                    contentRight: [ 
                        new sap.m.Button({
                            text: "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">filter}",
                            icon : "sap-icon://action",
                            visible: "{"+Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP+">/formVisible}",
                            iconFirst: false,
                            press: [oController.filterAndExpand, oController]
                        }),
                        new sap.m.Button({
                            text: "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">clean}",
                            icon: "sap-icon://action",
                            iconFirst: false,
                            visible: "{"+Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP+">/formVisible}",
                            press: [oController.cleanForm, oController]
                        }),
                        new sap.m.Button({
                            text: "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">hide}",
                            icon: "sap-icon://action",
                            iconFirst: false,
                            visible: "{"+Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP+">/formVisible}",
                            press: [oController.hideOrShowForm, oController]
                        }),
                        new sap.m.Button({
                            text: "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">show}",
                            icon: "sap-icon://action",
                            iconFirst: false,
                            visible: {
                                path:Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP+">/formVisible",
                                formatter: formatter.generic.negate
                            }, 
                            press: [oController.hideOrShowForm, oController]
                        })
                    ]
                }).addStyleClass("greyBar"),
```

Method where I change my property:

```
hideOrShowForm : function(evt){
    var inputModel = this.getView().getModel(Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP);
    inputModel.setProperty("/formVisible", !(inputModel.getProperty("/formVisible")));
    inputModel.updateBindings();        
    this.getView().invalidate();
}
```

So to sum it all, my view gets the initial value(Tried with false aswell) but does not get updated when I change it in my code.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I am sharing the rest of the code of my view just in case something is wrong.

```
sap.ui.jsview("view.UserFinderHelp",{
getControllerName : function() {
    return "controller.UserFinderHelp";
},
createContent : function(oController){
    return new sap.m.Dialog({
        draggable:true,
        id: Constants.ID.USER_FINDER_HELP,
        contentWidth: "50%",
        contentHeight: "80%",
        showHeader: true,
        verticalScrolling:false,
        horizontalScrolling:false,
        escapeHandler: oController.onClose,
        customHeader: new sap.m.Bar({
            contentLeft: [
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">usersFinder}"
                })
            ],
            contentRight: [
                new sap.m.Button({
                    icon: "sap-icon://decline",
                    customData:[
                        new sap.ui.core.CustomData({
                            key: "viewId",
                            value: this.getId()
                        })
                    ], 
                    press: [oController.onClose, oController]              
                })
            ],


         }).addStyleClass("sapMBarTitle"),
        content:[
            new sap.m.Bar({
                contentLeft:[
                    new sap.m.Text({
                        text: "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">finderParameters}"
                    })
                ]

            }).addStyleClass("sapMBarSubTitle"),
            new sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm({
                editable: true,
                layout: sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleFormLayout.ResponsiveGridLayout,
                labelSpanXL: 1,
                labelSpanL: 2,
                labelSpanM: 2,
                labelSpanS: 3,
                visible:"{"+Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP+">/formVisible}",
                content: [                                                
                    new sap.m.VBox({
                    visible : true,   
                    items:[
                        new sap.m.HBox({
                            items: [
                                new sap.m.RadioButton({

                                    groupName : "Group1",
                                    text : "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">completeName}",
                                    select : [oController.controlCampos, oController],
                                    selected : true,                                
                                }),
                                new sap.m.Input("inputNombre",{
                                    enabled : "{"+Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP+">/inputEditable}",                                                                                
                                    //type : sap.m.InputType.Text,
                                    placeholder : "Introduzca nombre completo"
                                })
                            ]
                        }),
                        new sap.m.HBox({
                            items : [
                                new sap.m.RadioButton({
                                    groupName : "Group1",
                                    text : "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">user}",                             
                                }),
                                new sap.m.Input("inputUsuario",{                                        
                                    enabled : 
                                    {
                                        path: Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP+">/inputEditable",       
                                        formatter : formatter.generic.negate                                     
                                    },
                                    //type : sap.m.InputType.Text,
                                    placeholder : "Usuario" //TODO i18n
                                })
                            ]
                        })


                    ]
                   })
                ]
                }).addStyleClass("scopeSelectorForm"), 

                new sap.m.Bar({
                    contentRight: [ 
                        new sap.m.Button({
                            text: "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">search}",
                            icon : "sap-icon://action",
                            visible: "{"+Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP+">/formVisible}",
                            iconFirst: false,
                            press: [oController.filterAndExpand, oController]
                        }),
                        new sap.m.Button({
                            text: "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">clean}",
                            icon: "sap-icon://action",
                            iconFirst: false,
                            visible: "{"+Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP+">/formVisible}",
                            press: [oController.cleanForm, oController]
                        }),
                        new sap.m.Button({
                            text: "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">hide}",
                            icon: "sap-icon://action",
                            iconFirst: false,
                            visible: "{"+Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP+">/formVisible}",
                            press: [oController.hideOrShowForm, oController]
                        }),
                        new sap.m.Button({
                            text: "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">show}",
                            icon: "sap-icon://action",
                            iconFirst: false,
                            visible: {
                                path:Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP+">/formVisible",
                                formatter: formatter.generic.negate
                            }, 
                            press: [oController.hideOrShowForm, oController]
                        })
                    ]
                }).addStyleClass("greyBar"),
                new sap.ui.table.Table({
                    //rows : "{"+Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP_RESULTS+">/userScopeList}",
                    items : {
                        path: Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP_RESULTS+">/userScopeList",
                        template : new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                            cells:[
                                new sap.m.Text({
                                text: "{"+Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP_RESULTS+">login}"
                            }),
                                new sap.m.Text({
                                    text: "{"+Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP_RESULTS+">name}"
                                })
                            ]
                        })
                    },
                    columns : [
                        new sap.ui.table.Column({
                            label : new sap.m.Label({
                                text : "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">user}"
                            })                                 
                        }),
                        new sap.ui.table.Column({
                            label : new sap.m.Label({
                                text : "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">completeName}"
                            })

                        })
                    ]
                })                                        
        ],
        buttons : [
            new sap.m.Button({
                text:  "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">Continue}"                    
            }),
            new sap.m.Button({
                text: "{"+Constants.MODEL.I18N+">cancel}",
                press: [oController.onClose, oController]        
            })
        ]

}).addEventDelegate({
    onBeforeRendering: function(evt){
        sap.ui.getCore().byId(Constants.ID.APP).addDependent(evt.srcControl);
    },

}).addStyleClass("UserFinderDialog")

}

});
```

Comment: I guess you need to provide more code. Currently, I don't see any problem. The model is bound to the view, you update the model, and thus the change should be reflected in the UI as long as the binding mode is not `OneTime`. Does negating `inputEditable` work? How is the SimpleForm added to the UI anyway? Is the snippet from JSView?

Comment: I do not think providing more code will be of any use, because I tried this with just what I showed already. 
I never set the binding to `OneTime`, but can you tell me how to put it to `TwoTime` binding? 
The SimpleForm is the content of a Dialog.
Yes. This code is part of a JSView.

Thank you for taking the time of reading and answering.

Comment: Setting the binding mode to `TwoWay` doesn't help. And the default binding mode of JSONModel is already `TwoWay`.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a minimal and executable example (e.g. via [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/)) in which we can reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I think it's related to your use of sap.m.Dialog as a root control of your view in conjunction with your use of addDependent. Did you try without the additional addDependent? Does this.getView correctly return the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out why this happened. Because my view is a Dialog which was invoked with a ComponentLoader. I did not think that I was actually binding it to the view which invokes mine.

Instead I just binded it like this:

```
 this.getView().getContent()[0].setModel(inputModel, Constants.MODEL.USER_FINDER_HELP);
```

Thanks to those who helped me!

Answer (score 1):

If two way binding is active this should be no problem.

See example: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/tyel123/nmjfs8d8/)

```js
sap.ui.controller("myController", {
  onInit: function() {


    var jsonData = {
      text: "secondButton",
      formVisible: true
    };
    var jsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(jsonData);
    this.getView().setModel(jsonModel, "myModel");

  },

  hideOrShowForm: function(evt) {
    var inputModel = this.getView().getModel("myModel");
    inputModel.setProperty("/formVisible", !(inputModel.getProperty("/formVisible")));
  }

});

sap.ui.view({
  viewContent: jQuery('#myXml').html(),
  type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML
}).placeAt("content");
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.ui.layout,sap.suite.ui.commons, sap.ui.commons, sap.ui.table" data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">
</script>

<script id="myXml" type="text/xmldata">
  <mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="myController" displayBlock="true">
    <App>
      <Page>
        <Panel>

          <Button text="Press" type="None" iconFirst="true" width="auto" enabled="true" iconDensityAware="false" press="hideOrShowForm" />


          <Button text="{myModel>/text}" type="None" iconFirst="true" width="auto" enabled="true" visible="{myModel>/formVisible}" iconDensityAware="false" />

        </Panel>
      </Page>
    </App>
  </mvc:View>
</script>

<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

regards

Comment: This example works, but it's not because the binding mode is `TwoWay`. Since the data change comes from the model instead of from a control, it works with `OneWay` too. The question author needs to provide more code to find the real issue.

Comment: The example is exactly the same thing I got but with an xml view. 

Thanks for taking the time to help.